# Difficulty with Götz Aly's "Hitlers Volksstaat [...]" passage

Tags: meaning, sentence-structure, grammatical-case, noun

Could you help me breakdown the following passage from Götz Aly's "Hitlers Volksstaat. Raub, Rassenkrieg und nationaler Sozialismus":

> 1937 verlieh Hitler dem Grafen mit Goldenen Parteiabzeichen die Ehrenmitgliedschaft in der NSDAP Hinfort verwandte Schwerin von Krosigk in schwierigen Fällen die Anrede »lieber Parteigenosse« und ließ sie sich selbst gefallen.

I'm unable to parse it: I cannot detect the clauses' boundaries nor assign each part its correct function.

We cannot discard a potential spelling error (actually "NSDAP" itself is written "NSDAR").

Also "Hinfort" spelt this way (uppercase) suggests some noun meaning missing from every german dictionary I could set my eyes on.

Comment: I agree with the necessary full stop before *Hinfort*; this means just *from then on* or *afterwards* and is considered dated in the sense, that no one would use it except for VERY formal texts.

Comment: Quelle offenbar: https://books.google.de/books?id=XgFrAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT16&lpg=PT16&dq=Hitler+dem+Grafen+mit+Goldenem+Parteiabzeichen&source=bl&ots=N5A83iyQim&sig=VboYe_Stz2OrXUUep3eqsCUIUuk&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjAgNTzscLSAhVC0xQKHSxDArQQ6AEIODAI#v=onepage&q=Hitler%20dem%20Grafen%20mit%20Goldenem%20Parteiabzeichen&f=false - ein Scanfehler. Der Punkt wurde mit dem P zu einem R verschmolzen. Das deutet auf einen fehlerträchtigen Scanprozess hin, der auch satt "Goldenem" zu "Goldenen" (Mz.?) Parteiabzeichen führte. Als Eigenname nicht zu Unrecht groß geschrieben.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a typo.
There should be a full stop between "NSDAP" and "Hinfort". Additionally, I suspect that "Goldenen" should be "Goldenem".

**Update:** "Goldenen" is correct, but the article "dem" is missing, see Hubert Schölnast's link to Google Books.

Comment: "Goldenen" would be correct, if "Parteiabzeichen" is plural.

Comment: @IQV Yes, but does plural make sense here?

Answer (score 3):

We are not a translation service, so we normally don't translate individual texts, but I think we can make an exception in this case.

You can read the correct quote here: [google books: Hitlers Volksstaat: Raub, Rassenkrieg und nationaler Sozialismus; von Götz Aly](https://books.google.at/books?id=XgFrAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT16&lpg=PT16&dq=1937%20verlieh%20Hitler%20dem%20Grafen%20mit%20Goldenen%20Parteiabzeichen%20die%20Ehrenmitgliedschaft%20in%20der%20NSDAP&source=bl&ots=N5A83iyLln&sig=hjhcSlzUwfAuDZwsITCJEyWH00g&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_n_iTsMLSAhWGWxQKHQJOA94Q6AEIJDAB#v=onepage&q=1937%20verlieh%20Hitler%20dem%20Grafen%20mit%20Goldenen%20Parteiabzeichen%20die%20Ehrenmitgliedschaft%20in%20der%20NSDAP&f=false)

Googles optical character recognition obviously made an error: It should be »NSDAP.« but you can read »NSDAR«. Google converted the P plus the full stop into an R.

This is the correct German text:

> 1937 verlieh Hitler dem Grafen mit **dem** Goldenen Parteiabzeichen die Ehrenmitgliedschaft in der NSDA**P.** Hinfort verwandte Schwerin von Krosigk in schwierigen Fällen die Anrede »lieber Parteigenosse« und ließ sie sich selbst gefallen.

And this is my translation

> In 1937 Hitler bestowed the honorary membership in the NSDAP on the Count with the Golden Party Badge. Henceforth Schwerin von Krosigk, in difficult cases, used the address "dear party comrade" and he also enjoyed to be addressed this way.